# Book on linear algebra containing interesting problems

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

Could anyone suggest me a problem book on linear algebra that contains interesting problems on rank, nullity, nullspace, linear transformations, eigenvalues, eigenvectors and characteristic polynomials? In other words, a good problem book on linear algebra is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Linear algebra - Challenging problems for students" of Fuzhen Zhang

"Linear algebra problem book" of Halmos

Answer (score 1):

Linear algebra by Gilbert Strang 
[Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0961408855)
It was used In MIT (open course ware)

Answer (score 0):

- Linear Algebra Problem book by [Halmos](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=SY-_COzW4toC&printsec=frontcover&dq=book+problems+in+linear+algebra&hl=en&sa=X&ei=23xxVdGRN4LVuQTzqpbIBQ&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=book%20problems%20in%20linear%20algebra&f=false)
- 3,000 Solved Problems in Linear Algebra by [Seymour Lipschutz](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=_8Zs6UY0oM8C&q=book+problems+in+linear+algebra&dq=book+problems+in+linear+algebra&hl=en&sa=X&ei=23xxVdGRN4LVuQTzqpbIBQ&ved=0CDIQ6AEwBA)